# Restrict 3rd party apps to access Internet except one app in Android

Tags: android, service

I am developing an Android Application for examination purpose. This app will be used by students and professors. Student may attempt to verify the answer from other apps by using Internet during the exam. The client want's to restrict other android apps to use Internet service when the exam app is open. Is it possible to disable Internet Access of other apps when a particular app is open?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. But in your 'exame app' you can check when your Activities are in foreground or not. If your app goes in background, you can assume that the student is trying to do something else. What about?

Comment: thanks for the solution.But it may also happen that higher priority system call (unmaskable events)appears while the student is appearing for exam e.g.,Call. How to tackle such situation?

Comment: @JayLakhani - Honestly every 'security mechanism' implemented client side is never secure. For example one of the student could get the apk of the app, modify the code by removing all restrictions, and install it again. So if you're looking for an unattackable solution, you should consider other ways (server side). For example: can you remove the SIM card from the devices? Is the app downloading something related to the exam from the network? If you can remove the sim card, you could give WiFi access to students and let the 'question server' be reachable only from that network.